# How to set Day, Month and Year in a DatePicker Field in custom HTML forms - Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, jquery-ui-datepicker

I don't know how to populate a Datepicker. I have a function "Edit data", when the user clicks on this button, a custom HTML form is opened and all the data of a spreadsheet is showing there. The part of the TextField was easy, was just `TextField.value = data[1]`, but for type Date, I don't know how to do this, my code is that:

```
function pesquisarContrato(){

var dashboard = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Dashboard');
var planContrato = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Contratos');
var contrato = dashboard.getRange("G3").getValue();
if(contrato == ""){return false;}
var dados = planContrato.getRange(3,1, planContrato.getLastRow(), 27).getValues();

for(var linha = 0; linha<dados.length; linha++) {

  if(dados[linha][0] == contrato) {

      var dados_completos = {}

      dados_completos.id_contrato = dados[linha][0];
      dados_completos.licitacao = dados[linha][1];
      dados_completos.nsipac = dados[linha][2];
      dados_completos.objetivo = dados[linha][3];
      dados_completos.empresa = dados[linha][4];
      dados_completos.cnpj = dados[linha][5];

      //here, I get the day of data with custom function ToDate()
      dados_completos.inicioVigencia = toDate(linha,6)[0];
   
      return ([dados_completos.id_contrato, dados_completos.licitacao,
          dados_completos.nsipac, dados_completos.objetivo, 
          dados_completos.empresa, dados_completos.cnpj, 
          dados_completos.inicioVigencia])
    }

function toDate(linha, coluna){

    var planContrato = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Contratos');

    var dados = planContrato.getRange(3,1, planContrato.getLastRow(), 27).getValues();

    var d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dados[linha][coluna]), Session.getScriptTimeZone, "dd/MM/yyyy");
    var split = d.split('/');

    // Month is zero-indexed so subtract one from the month inside the constructor
    var date = new Date(split[2], split[1]-1,split[0]); //Y M D 
    var day = date.getDate();;
    var month = date.getMonth()+1;
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    var date_completa = {};

    date_completa.day = day;
    date_completa.month = month;
    date_completa.year = year;


    return ([date_completa.day, date_completa.month, date_completa.year])
}
```

HTML part:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s3">
        <input id="iniciogarantia" type="date" class="validate">
        <label for="iniciogarantia">Início da garantia</label>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(pesquisar).pesquisarContrato();

    var campoContrato = document.getElementById("contrato");
    var campoLicitacao = document.getElementById("licitacao");
    var campoSipac = document.getElementById("sipac");
    var campoObjetivo = document.getElementById("objetivo");
    var campoEmpresa = document.getElementById("empresa");
    var campoCnpj = document.getElementById("cnpj");
    var campoIniciovigencia = document.getElementById("iniciovigencia");

    function pesquisar(atualizar){

        campoContrato.value = atualizar[0];
        campoLicitacao.value = atualizar[1];
        campoSipac.value = atualizar[2];
        campoObjetivo.value = atualizar[3];
        campoEmpresa.value = atualizar[4];
        campoCnpj.value = atualizar[5]; 

        // this part have an issue, .value don't works for datepicker,
        // so how can I populate this field?
        //campoIniciovigencia.? = atualizar[6];

        M.updateTextFields();       
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Looking at your toDate function, it returns an array of [day, month, year]. A date type takes as an input the string value of a date, for example `<input type="date" value="2021-07-08">`. So you could generate the string using the values from toDate and add that as a value. Make sure to adhere to the format: yyyy-mm-dd (two digits for months and days).

Answer (score 0):

Replace **ALL** lines after

```js
var d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dados[linha][coluna]), Session.getScriptTimeZone, "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

by:

```js
return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dados[linha][coluna]), Session.getScriptTimeZone, "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Also:

dados_completos.inicioVigencia = toDate(linha,6)<s>[0]</s>;